# Sum a sub query

Tags: sql-server

My query:

```
select  sum(round(fQtyOut*(select fCostAVRR from item where item.ccode=ItmUpTrn.cItemCode),3)) from ItmUpTrn
where cInvoiceNo=  'C2-19584'
```

Returns:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I need only one field with the total value. How can I do this?

Comment: have you searched the site for that error as there are plenty of posts about it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+perform+an+aggregate+function+on+an+expression+containing+an+aggregate+or+a+subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this instead ?

```
SELECT 
  round(sum(ItmUpTrn.fQtyOut*item.fCostAVRR),3) 
  --sum(round(ItmUpTrn.fQtyOut*item.fCostAVRR,3)) 
FROM ItmUpTrn
JOIN item
on item.ccode=ItmUpTrn.cItemCode
WHERE ItmUpTrn.cInvoiceNo=  'C2-19584'
```

Please note I would round off after sum. It is faster and more accurate, if this is not what you need, you can change it back

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much
You are my SAVIOR